# Excel help removing 45303 from spreadhseet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to remove the 45303 number in column C.  This appears only  when data fields are empty but the formula works when data is entered. The formula is `=IF(U5="",TODAY()-E5,U5-E5)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can nest IF statements to check for E5 being empty. I modified the formula for row 2 below.

Try something like this:

```
=IF(E2<>"",IF(U2="",TODAY()-E2,U2-E2),"")
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried something very similar from research and it did not work, this seems to work, I know the 45303 is actually a date but  since the format is general is is displaying the 45303